# Nodejs get user by id

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, http, ionic-framework

Am using the MEAN stack for an `app`, i have users that i register and log in using `satellizer` everything work well.

But when i try to `get` user by it's id i get nothing, i can do request to get all users but not by id.

Note am using Ionicframework as a forntEnd framework.
Here is the code of my back end end point:

```
app.get('/api/me', function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.user, function(err, user) {
    console.log(req.user);
    console.log(user);
    res.send(user);
  });
})
```

my Front end code the controller:

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, $ionicLoading, $timeout, $stateParams) {

    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: 'Loading...'
    });

    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/me')
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log("Recived data via HTTP", data);

            $timeout(function() {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $scope.user = data;
            }, 1000);
        })
        .error(function() {
            console.log("Error while getting the data");
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        });
})
```

Request Header:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6,fi;q=0.4,it;q=0.2,en-GB;q=0.2,en-CA;q=0.2
Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1NTAxYjAxMmExMjRlZjIwMTc4M2ExMTQiLCJleHAiOjE0MjcxMzk0NDV9.x9QEdE4E-Vh1SklCheiZqsnJsg8jGzdJnPx2RXeZqS8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
```

Comment: What's the value of `req.user` before the `User.findById` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missed an important part in your server call, the "ensureAuthenticated":

```
app.get('/api/me', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
   User.findById(req.user, function(err, user) {
    res.send(user);
 });
});
```

the `ensureAuthenticate` of this satellite example implemenation is a very simple version, it only puts the content of the token.sub into req.user. This is good enough for your query. Typically in a real app one would use passport middleware instead, load the user in the middleware and put it into req.user.

when using the mean stack typically `req.user` is set to the full user object, i.e. an instance of mongoose document. You want to search by id, so give the query an id:

try

```
User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user) {
```

instead.

But, considering that req.user is already exactly the object that you are querying for, the whole query might just not be needed at all.

If you want to look up a different user than the authenticated one, you need to pass the id you want to query in the URL path, typically something like:

```
GET /api/users/{id}
```

then you can get this id using

```
req.params.id
```

and pass it to the `findById()` call

Comment: i tried it i got this Error Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Comment: ok, this means, that you are not authenticated. req.user being undefined is the way passport tells you that there is no logged in user. For a RESTFul API you need to pass the credentials with every call, typically done in angular by setting auth headers on $http

Comment: Ok, but if am not authenticated. How i find the user in my db after Registration .!

Comment: first check whether the user really is stored in the DB (using mongo CLI or some mongoDB UI). then check whether your angular app is sending auth headers (using Browser developer console). then check whether the 'passport' authentication middleware is setup in your node.js / express routing.

Comment: the user in the DB i did checked, also i can do Find function to get all the user i have in DB working fine. 

and this the request header: ill add it to the question because it looked messy in a comment

The passport middleware is set

Comment: did you follow this example express implementation of satellite? https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/node/server.js

Comment: there is a very simple but important mistake in your server implementation, I put it in the anwer above: ensureAuthenticated is missing in your code

Comment: True, but the name of the function make me feel its a security check that i don't want to do in prototype.. Thank you .

Comment: look at the implementation of the ensureAuthenticated method, there the req.user is set, very simple...